# onClick function inside a form with submit button causes error

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

When I use JavaScript button with onClick function inside the form tag in frontend.php, it causes mistake. I need this simple application that does simple job, but it got stuck at this.

I provide you two links. First is within the form tag (frontend.php) and there it doesn't work - ADDMORE BUTTON SIMPLY DOESN'T ADD MORE TEXTAREAS! And the second link is without the form tag, and it works, you can try and submit which will leave you to the welldone.php page.

[1.LINK - There is a problem](http://balkanex.info/dev/backend.html)

[2.LINK - No form tag, no problem](http://balkanex.info/dev/backend2.html)

**HTML FORM**

```
<form action="http://www.balkanex.info/dev/frontend.php" method="post">
    Title: <br/><input type="text" name="title"><br/><br/>
    The question is: <br/><input type="text" name="ask"><br/><br/>
<br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="PROCEED"><br/>
</form>
```

**FRONTEND.PHP FILE**

```
<script>
am = 1;
function more(index) {
        am++;
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "answer" + am;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("inner1").appendChild(div);
}
</script>

<?php
echo '<form action="welldone.php" method="post">';
$content = "";
$title = $_POST['title'];
$question = $_POST['ask'];

if($_POST['ask'] != "") {
    $answer = '<textarea name="answer1"></textarea>';
    $more = '<button type="button" name="more" onClick="more();">Add more</button>';
    $content .= '1) '.$question.'<br/>'.$answer.'<br/><div id="inner1"></div>'.$more.'<br/><br/>';
}
echo $content;
echo'<br/><input type="submit" value="CALCULATE"></form>';
?>
```

**RESULTS WELLDONE.PHP FILE**

```
<?php
echo 'WOW, WELL DONE';
?>
```

Comment: The name of the element is the same as the function, so the element name is overwriting the function in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when you use `more`, browser is uses `<button name="more">` instead of `function more`. Then, you get

```
TypeError: more is not a function
```

This behavior is only present in forms, that's why without forms your code works.

You can fix it doing one of these:

- Changing function name
- Changing button name
- Writing unobtrusive javascript, adding the event handler from a `<script>` element instead ofthe inline `onclick` attribute.

Anyway, your code is completely invalid and in quirks mode. You should validate it and fix the errors.

Comment: Thanx for suggestions. What do u mean by saying that the code is invalid and in quirks mode. How to validate? I'm blonde :D

Comment: @user3392725 :S I don't understand, I was sure I linked the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/). [Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) means that you don't have a doctype, so some browsers (basically IE) behave non-standard.